# Remove newline from textfile conditionally in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a simple text file, something like:

**Input**

```
texta texta texta texta texta texta
texta

textb textb textb textb textb

textc textc textc textc
textc textc
textc textc textc

textd textd textd
```

I want to use the tidyverse to remove all the newlines if they are not followed by a blank line.

**Expected output**

```
texta texta texta texta texta texta texta

textb textb textb textb textb

textc textc textc textc textc textc textc textc textc

textd textd textd
```

**Attempt**

I thought the first step should be to import the data in R and store it as a data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_lines("input.txt", skip_empty_rows = FALSE, na = "") %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

And the next step should be something like a `transmute` function? Or am I completely wrong, and is there an easier way to import the data?

How would you perform this operation using the Tidyverse in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable with `cumsum` on the blank elements and `paste` them

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col1 = lines) %>% 
      group_by(grp = cumsum(col1 == '')) %>%
      summarise(col = trimws(str_c(col1, collapse=" ")), .groups = 'drop') %>%
      select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  col                                                  
#  <chr>                                                
#1 texta texta texta texta texta texta texta            
#2 textb textb textb textb textb                        
#3 textc textc textc textc textc textc textc textc textc
#4 textd textd textd
```

---

We create the grouping by first converting the column to a logical vector (`col1 == ''`), then do the cumulative sum, so that for every TRUE value i.e. a blank element, it gets added 1 because `TRUE -> 1` and `FALSE -> 0`.  This grouping helps to block the elements that are in the 'col1' as a single group, and then we `paste` them with `str_c` (from `stringr`) to return a single string for each group

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("input.txt")
```